# Both Reading and writing to a file

Tags: perl, csv

I am new to perl and am trying to read and write to a csv file in perl. But nothing happens can some one help me where the problem is. I am able to read without a problem using '<' but I am unable to write.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $file = 'file.csv';    
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new();

open (InCSV, '+>>', $file) or die $!;
while (<InCSV>) {
    if ($csv->parse($_)) {
        my @columns = $csv->fields();
        if($columns[1] eq "01") {
               my $str = "Selected $columns[6] \n ";
               push(@columns,$str);

               print InCSV join("," , @columns), "\n";
        }                  
    } else {
        my $err = $csv->error_input;
        print "Failed to parse line: $err";
    }
}
close InCSV;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Opening a file in `+>>` mode will seek to the end of the file, so there will be nothing to read unless you `seek` back to the beginning (or the middle) of the file. To open in read/write mode with the file cursor at the beginning of the file, use `+<` mode.

That said, you probably want to rethink your approach to this problem. It looks like you are trying to read a row of data, modify it, and write it back to the file. But the way you have done it, you are overwriting the *next* row of data rather than the row you have just read, and anyway the new data is longer (has more bytes) than the old data. This is certain to corrupt your data file.

Some better approaches might be to

- read and process all data first, then close and overwrite the input with processed data
- write data to a temporary file while you are processing it, then overwrite the input with the temporary file (see also about the perl interpreter's [in-place editing mode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlrun#i))
- use a module like `Tie::File` to handle the line-based I/O for this task

Comment: when I am writing  using +< the console is getting stuck when writing. Another thing is I dont want to modify all the rows. I want to  write to only specific rows where the condition is met. So writing to a diffrent file or storing is going to be a problem. Is there a better way ?

Comment: In general you can modify the data in-place if (1) the modified data is exactly the same size as the original data, or (2) the data to modify is at the end of the file. Otherwise, you will corrupt your data. 

Still, it looks like you have a pretty typical task. Why not use a typical solution? Keep processed data in memory or a temporary file, and then overwrite the input file.

Comment: i guess the misunderstanding here is to distinguish between reading and writing. as said open with open(3) and '<', read then close the handler. process the data. then again open(3) with '>' or '>>' and write.

Comment: hi I solved this problem by appending the string and writing to a new file seperated by commas and it worked

Comment: I agree with mob: You should read the data from the file, process it,  write to another file, then move the new one to the old name. Otherwise, what would happen if your program fails in the middle of the task? You'll have a damaged file and can't rerun your program. Plus, this gives you the ability to test your results by simply not doing the last step. Then, when everything is good, add in the replace step.