# substitute a string with another in-place

Tags: perl, cygwin

In this example I would like to modify the file in-place (without pie):

```
# Initialise file
open my $fh, '>', 'test';
print $fh 'I love apples';
close $fh;

# Do the replacement
open $fh, '+<', 'test';
s/love/hate/ while(<$fh>);
close $fh;

# Test content (should be 'I hate apples')
open $fh, '<', 'test';
print while(<$fh>);
close $fh;
```

Unfortunately this example does not work. I only find this ugly solution:

```
# Do the replacement
open $fh, '<', 'test';
my $out;
my $changes;
while(<$fh>) {
    $changes += $_ =~ s/love/hate/;
    $out.=$_;
}
if($changes) {
    open $fh, '>', 'test';
    print $fh $out;
}
close $fh;
```

Any better solution?

Requirement: I only want to touch my file if there is something to change. 
Hint:        I'm on Windows/Cygwin :(

Comment: You seem to be looking for read, seek back, print. It'll be more ugly that reading the whole file into memory and printing it back out.

Comment: Is it even the case for large files?

Comment: huh? The looks of the code aren't affected by the size of data file.

Comment: I mean if I have to replace 1 line located somewhere at the beginning of a large file. With my second method I will load the entire file into memory then write it back to disk. The seek back solution should be a bit better isn't?

Comment: Depends on the criteria with which you are evaluating them. In some context, neither are as good as a solution that outputs to new file then moves the new file over the original (since it won't corrupt your file if there's an error).

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of the `+<` file open mode in your first example. It is not an "edit in-place" mode, it just means you can both read and print to the same handle. Most of the time, this is not what you want, and its more complicated and bug prone than any alternatives.

Comment: If you want to edit in-place, like the `pie` switches do, then you might be interested in the `$^I` variable combined with the `<>` handle. You can see how it works in the `pie` variant if you deparse the code: `perl -MO=Deparse -pi -e0`. Or read about it in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$^I).

Comment: related: [Perl editting a file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4889755/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the substitution has the same length; you have to rewrite the file from the substitution point forward to insert/erase even a letter in it.

`-i` option is usually implemented using a temporary file. All your changes are written to a temporary file that is renamed at the end to the original filename:

```
$ perl -i -pe's/a/bc/g' input1
$ <input2 perl -pe's/a/bc/g' >output && replace output input2
$ <input3 perl -pe's/a/bc/g' | sponge input3
```

i.e.,

```
while(<$fhorig>) {
  $changed += $_ =~ s/love/haaate/;
  print $fhtmp $_;
}
# close, fsync files..
rename $tmp, $orig if $changed;
```

If input file is small; you could make changes in memory instead without the temporary file. Your code in the question does it.

If the substitution has the same length then you could mmap the file and make the changes inplace. Both Windows and Unix support mmap. It allows to work with a large file as though it were a string or you could emulate it using read/seek/write.

Answer (score 2):

Relevant documentation:

- [perlfaq5 - How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)
- [perlfaq5 - How can I use Perl's -i option from within a program?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-use-Perl's--i-option-from-within-a-program%3f)

In your case, I would recommend using [`$INPLACE_EDIT`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) as modeled in either of the above two faq entries.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'test';

# Initialise file
open my $fh, '>', $file;
print $fh <DATA>;
close $fh;

# Do the replacement
local @ARGV = $file;
local $^I   = '.bak';
while (<>) {
    s/love/hate/;
    print;
}
unlink "$file$^I";    # Optionally delete backup

# Test content (should be 'I hate apples')
open $fh, '<', 'test';
print <$fh>;
close $fh;

__DATA__
I love apples
I love oranges
I love bananas
```

Outputs:

```
I hate apples
I hate oranges
I hate bananas
```

Note: if you're on Windows, then you're required to specify a backup extension for `-i`.  Therefore, I always do so to be cross platform compatible.

Comment: `$^I` violates: *"Requirement: I only want to touch my file if there is something to change"* but it seems OP is ok with it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian good remark and the award comes back to you. But The  Miller's answer is beautiful!